# Vue2: Conditionally bind href to A tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I can successfully bind a links to A tags but it seems doesn't like my conditions. My intention is "NOT TO bind an href attribute if `pageName === item.name`". Somehow unless I write something like `:href="pageName === item.name ? 'some text here' : item.link"`, it always renders href.

For example, if `pageName = 'listing'`, I expect `<a href=""></a>` but I get `<a href="/listing"></a>` instead. Not sure which part I did wrong.

Ideally, I would expect `<a></a>` if `pageName = 'listing'` but I don't know how to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

```js
var globalNav = {
    props: ['pageName'],
    template:  `<div id="global-nav">
                    <a 
                            class="nav-item"
                            v-for="(item, i) in items"
                            :key="i + 1"
                            :active="pageName === item.name"
                            :href="pageName === item.name ? '' : item.link"
                    >
                        <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                        <div class="tooltip">
                            <div class="arrow"></div>
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Dashboard',
                    icon: 'icon-home',
                    link: '/',
                    name: 'dashboard'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Listing',
                    icon: 'icon-listing',
                    link: '/listing',
                    name: 'listing'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Import',
                    icon: 'icon-stackoverflow',
                    link: '/import',
                    name: 'import'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Settings',
                    icon: 'icon-cog',
                    link: '/settings',
                    name: 'settings'
                },
            ]
        };
    }
};

var header = new Vue({
    el: '#header',
    components: {
        'global-nav': globalNav
    },
    data: {
        pageName: pageName
    },
    methods: {
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You should use conditional binding (`:href="pageName === item.name ? 'some text here' : item.link"`). Everything else seems weird to me and sounds like it should not work :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `:href="item.link"` there? Why use conditions? I understand conditional in `active` but not in href?

Comment: Hi Traxo, as all items have the link field with values, the active page will be binded an href link and clickable if I don't remove the link from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend the structure you used for your implementation of navigation but I have a workaround for your problem.
You can use `<template>` tags with `v-if` condition on `a` tags like this:

```
template:  `<div id="global-nav">
                <template  v-for="(item, i) in items">
                    <a v-if="pageName !== item.name"
                            class="nav-item"
                            :key="i + 1"
                            :active="pageName === item.name"
                            :href="item.link">
                        <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                        <div class="tooltip">
                            <div class="arrow"></div>
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a v-else>
                     <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                        <div class="tooltip">
                            <div class="arrow"></div>
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </template>
            </div>`,
```

Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywyw96o83j) (don't mind the rest of the files in the example, only the App.vue. I hardcoded the `pageName` property for the sake of the example)

Comment: Thank allkin, understood. So using v-if and v-else will definitely not render the parts I don't want. When you mentioned "not recommend the structure", I'm very interested in what's the best structure to use in this scenario.
BTW, I'm using pure Vue in front end. Server side Vue is not supported here.